# Exclude a function in PHP (Wordpress)

Tags: php, html, wordpress, function

I recently purchased a Wordpress theme and having some problems with importing a feature from another theme (from the same author).

The author of the themes helped me a lot with importing some stuff to the new theme. While both themes share many similarities, there's still some tweaking that needs to be done.

One of the issues I'm currently facing is with a PHP file I imported from the original theme to the new one. Both Wordpress themes work with minisites, but the author coded them differently for each Wordpress.

When I copy/paste **boxes.php** from the old theme to the new theme, I get this error message:

**Fatal error: Call to undefined function it_get_minisite() in /home/vincevc73/domains/quirk.be/public_html/wp-content/themes/explicit/inc/boxes.php on line 13**

The author told me I had to exclude this, but I have no idea how to do this. I read I had to put `/*-*/` around the functions to exclude it, but I'm not sure where to put these marks **exactly**

The **it_get_minisite** function appears three times in the file

```
    $minisite = it_get_minisite($post->ID); 
    if($minisite)
    {
    #override general theme options with minisite-specific options
    $boxes_layout = $minisite->boxes_layout;
    }

   #get the current minisite $minisite = it_get_minisite($post->ID); 
   if($minisite)
   {
    #add post type to query args    
    if(it_targeted('boxes', $minisite))
           $boxesargs['post_type'] = $minisite->id;
   }

   $minisite = it_get_minisite(get_the_ID(), true);
```

Comment: Wordpress questions should be asked on [wordpress.se]

Comment: Have you tried commenting out the whole function and seeing what happens then?

Comment: include file in which it_get_minisite() is defined.

Answer (score 0):

I think he meant that you should remove all the code which requires this function. But then you will also have to remove the code which requires "$minisite" too. But that's only a guess based on the information you posted.